# Log-in no mysql apenas com sudo

Tags: mysql, linux, terminal, mariadb, deepin

Quando estou no terminal linux, na minha máquina e dou o comando :

```
mysql -u root -p
```

O terminal do linux apresenta :

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Com sudo antes do comando, consigo logar, porém, o que aparece na minha tela são linha de log-in do mariaDB

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 19
Server version: 10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.6

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: Certo, mas qual é a sua dúvida em relação à isso?

Comment: Só roda sudo mysql que vai logar direto e configura

Answer (score 0):

Nas novas versões MySql e MariaDB ele usam o plugin [unix_socket](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/8.0/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html) que usa as credencias do usuário para fazer a conexão ao banco.
Faça o seguinte teste, digite o comando
`$sudo mysql`
ou
`#mysql`
e vera que se ira se conectar ao banco e não precisara de informar usuário nem senha.
Para saber quais usuário tem essa configuração execute o seguinte SQL.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user where user = 'root';
+------+-----------+-------------+
| User | Host      | plugin      |
+------+-----------+-------------+
| root | localhost | unix_socket |
+------+-----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Da uma olhada nesse [fórum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost) também

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que vi tentou utilizar o sudo no inicio? Utiliza o Ubuntu? Utiliza O Java? Você precisa também criar uma senha para o Mysql se precisar comunicar com algumas aplicações, veja alguns post na internet tem vários, abraço!